# Stop an edited deleted answer from bumping the question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, bump

I just answered [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41964/pain-reliever-for-when-you-want-to-rid-yourself-of-a-downward-facing-question), then deleted the answer because I realized what I said had already been covered. After deleting, I editing in a note saying why I deleted it, but that edit bumped the question on the home page.

I assume that the question will get bumped if I undelete the answer (which is proper behaviour), but I think in the case where someone edits a deleted answer, there's no point bumping the question for content that most people aren't going to see (and since the answer is deleted, *shouldn't* be seen anyway).

**EDIT:** A nifty way to abuse the system (10k+ only!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, now that I have 10k, I understand this seemingly erroneous behaviour a lot more.

- Undeleting an answer doesn't bump the question (unlike what I said/assumed in the question) because this would be too easy to abuse with little history trace (you can still see it in the post revisions, but that's harder to access if there was no edit)
- Edits are more important to peer-review than deletes and undeletes (and, unlike delete/undelete, are possible to undo when you don't own the post)
- Using the same basic logic as normal posts keeps the system simpler

I think the idea is that if you're going to undelete an answer, it's highly likely that it will be edited during that process, which is generally sufficient to draw attention to the changes.

I think the use case I presented in the question was flawed, because there doesn't *need* to be a reason for me to delete an answer -- it's my post to delete as I choose. [@squillman provides](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/stop-an-edited-deleted-answer-from-bumping-the-question/42077#42077) a good workaround for giving a deletion reason.

Comment: However that gives a potential of "stealth reviving" a deleted answer: (1) Edit it while it is deleted, which will bump it, but since the answer is deleted, no one will likely care, and many users will not see the edit anyway. (2) Wait a period until the answer dropped again from the front page. (3) Undelete the answer. Why not make a rule that an undelete bumbs the question *if it has been edited after deletion,* while the edit of the deleted question itself doesn't?

Answer (score 8):

> EDIT: A nifty way to abuse the system (10k+ only!).

Well, yeah. But easily detected by other 10k users and mods (the last activity shows your name and the link goes straight to the deleted answer) - if you pulled that trick too often on the same post, you'd probably find yourself called to account.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Hmmm... I suppose the question would also be bumped by undeleting and immediately re-deleting the answer as well.

Comment: @Jon: Deleting or undeleting an answer doesn't bump the question, as far as I know.

Comment: @mmyers: I will try it and see.

Comment: @mmyers: You are correct, sir. Although, I have to say, undeleting probably *should* bump the question.

Comment: @Shog9: To get that straight, _deleting_ an answer doesn't bump the question, does it?

Comment: @Hendrik: nope.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I want to explain why I delete my post I put a comment in instead of editing the question.  Not sure if the bump you're talking about is intentional, but this is at least a workaround.

Comment: +1 for good workaround. I didn't think of doing that at the time.

Comment: I thought of a situation where this doesn't work. Let's say I gave an answer, but wanted to think about what I said, so I delete it. Then, to give a better answer, I edit the answer and then undelete. Even in this case, the edit should not bump the question since it will get bumped by the undelete (when, and if, I choose to do so).

Comment: You can't comment on a deleted answer. I'm not really sure how this solves the problem.

Comment: @Cody You put the comment in first, then delete the post.....