# Does deleting an answer bump its question at the top of the homepage?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderator-abilities, last-activity, trusted-user

I received a flag for a comment-as-an-answer answer to an off-topic closed question; last activity, September. Would this question be bumped to the top of the homepage if I removed the answer?

Yes, I know I could delete the question instead, but I personally frown upon breaking permalinks.

Comment: @Arjan Voting to delete answers is also a [20k power.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, deleting an answer does not bring a post to the front page.

Editing a deleted answer will, however.

Comment: When not deleted by its owner, right? Or am I really mistaken to think that deleting my own answers *does* bump the question?

Comment: @Arjan I've just deleted an answer, self-delete-wise. If the question shows up on the Meta front page on the next cycle, then there we go. But, I'm mostly sure it won't.

Comment: It appears it didn't indeed :)

Comment: I indeed stand corrected. Maybe I was mistaken by [Editing a deleted answer pokes the question to the top](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/editing-a-deleted-answer-pokes-the-question-to-the-top). Maybe things changed? Probably it's really my memory failing me! ;-)